# setting partition type in non-interactive parted command

Tags: linux, filesystems, parted, gdisk

I have a new disk in Linux (Centos):

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 536 MB, 536870912 bytes, 1048576 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I create GPT partition table and new partition with command:

```
# parted -a optimal --script /dev/sdb mklabel gpt mkpart primary 0% 100%
```

`fdisk -l` shows:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sdb: 536 MB, 536870912 bytes, 1048576 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 332CB746-DE7D-4FB0-AE34-D9B5CB008473


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048      1046527    510M  Microsoft basic primary
```

Why the `parted` commands does set type to "`Microsoft basic`"? How to set it to "`Linux filesystem`" using above command-line (non-interactive) `parted` command?

Currently, to change it I need to do it manually running "`gdisk /dev/sdb`" and then `t` and select code `8300`.

```
Command (? for help): t
Using 1
Current type is 'Microsoft basic data'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300):
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'
```

Another question is why when I create partition with above `parted` command and use `100%` for size it is finally 1MB smaller than when I created it  using `gdisk` command?

parted:

```
#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048      1046527    510M  Linux filesyste primary
```

gdisk:

```
#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048      1048542    511M  Linux filesyste Linux filesystem
```

Comment: First question, you didn't specify "toggle <partition> <flag>" - see the man page for parted. Second question, you can resize the partitions with parted (hence the name) but you can't resize the partitions with gdisk - the extra space required is the cost of being flexiable.